# Map point with coordinates to zones in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinates

I have a project in QGIS with two layers, one with several geographical zones (imported from a Shapefile file), and one with several points (imported from a CSV with longitude/latitude coordinates).

I would like to map each point to the ID of the zone that contains that point, i.e., create a new CSV in the form "longitude,latitude,ID". How can I do it in QGIS (or, possibly, any other "scripted" solution)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. After loading the CSV file, `right-click the file in the table of content -> Save as -> Choose shapefile format` and make sure you select the CRS that matches the polygon shapefile CSR
2. Use Join attribute by location that you can find it from `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join attribute by location`
3. Save the output file as a new shapefile
4. Then you can save the shapefile again as CSV by `right-click the file shapefile in the table of content -> Save as -> Choose CSV file`. In the `layer Option -> Geometry -> choose 'Default'` if you want to keep the original coordinate without appending another XY field to CSV output file, as you can see below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a "spatial join". In QGIS you can find such functionality under `Vector` -> `Data Management Tools` -> `Join attributes by location` or directly in the Processing Toolbox.